# Material -ui licence

Tags: material-ui

I have some freelance React projects for which I am  using MUI components  which includes these packages:-

"@material-ui/core": "4.11.1",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",

Now ,I have planned to upgrade  it to the latest version that is MUI V5.
While reading the migration documents and licensing documents ,I came across this link : -https://mui.com/store/license/

Just wanted to know what this license means for the community version?Do I need to purchase any license if I am using these packages in my projects?

I am a bit confused about the license mentioned here

Details about licensee and when it is needed

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong license. I think those are just for the store (templates). The libraries you are using should be MIT: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/LICENSE